# Code Igniter Controller Functions Incorrect in URL

Tags: php, codeigniter, xampp, url-routing

In CodeIgniter can I send `<form action="">` from view of one Controller to Other
Controller with its function

I am new to CodeIgniter and PHP, but am required to use it for a project , I am working on. Its been about 3 days, and I understand a good amount of how PHP and its framework is utilized, but I am struggling with one piece, The URL Changes.

From my understanding, the URL tags include the file directory, page, controller, and function in that order:-

```
 localhost/codeigniter/index.php/default_controller/default_function
```

In the project I am working on, the default view points to

```
localhost/codeigniter/
```

From here, the user selects an option from a dropdown, and clicks a submit button. On the  submittion, the URL changes to:-

```
localhost/codeigniter/index.php/default_controller/default_function
```

On this next page/view, there is another form that the user needs to fill out again. This time, when the button is clicked, the URL changes to:-

```
localhost/codeigniter/index.php/default_controller/index.php/second_controller/second_function
```

However, the correct destination is supposed to be

```
localhost/codeigniter/index.php/second_controller/second_function
```

Below is an example of how I am doing the data capture from the view to the controller, as I feel this may be useful in understanding the problem:

**VIEW - Default:-**

```
<form action="index.php/default_controller/default_function" method="POST">
    <select name="select">
        <?php
            foreach($options as $a => $b) {
                foreach($b as $key => $value) {
                    echo "<option value=".$a.">".$value."</option>";
                }
            }
        ?>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

**CONTROLLER - Default:-**

```
public function default_function() {
    $value = $this->input->post('select');
    $name = $this->default_model->get_by_id($value);
    $data['name'] = $name;
    $this->load->view('additional_attributes_view', $data);
}
```

**VIEW - Secondary:-**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Attributes</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Attributes</h1>
    <form action="index.php/secondary_controller/secondary_function" method="POST">
        <?php
            echo form_checkbox('server', 'server', TRUE);
        ?>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**CONTROLLER - Secondary:-**

```
<?php
  defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

  class secondary_controller extends CI_Controller {


   public function __construct() {
     parent::__construct();
     $this->load->helper('form');
     $this->load->helper('url');
   }

   public function secondary_function() {
     echo 'hello';
   }

}
```

From all of the google searches and youtube videos online, this was the best way I found to get a working relationship between the Controller and the View. It was said that the action parameter for the form in the view was the reference point for the application, and that is how it chooses where to redirect.

Comment: this is because you are making `2` different controllers like `Secondary` & `Default`

Comment: is your problem is solved???

Answer (score 0):

So for starters - what are your settings in application/config/config.php.

You need to set the **$config['base_url']** to your url.

It looks like you are still using the **$config['index_page'] = index.php** which is ok for now...

Once you have done that you can use **site_url()**

So set this to suit but it appears you should have...

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/codeigniter/';
```

Then you can use **site_url();** For instance

```
<form action="index.php/secondary_controller/secondary_function" method="POST">
```

would become

```
<form action="<?= site_url('secondary_controller/secondary_function) ;?>" method="POST">
```

The shortcode `<?= $x ;?>` is the same as `<?php echo $x ;?>`

I suggest as an exercise that you read the codeigniter user guide regarding both **site_url()** ( used for links)  and **base_url()** ( used for files like css, js etc );

Both **site_url()** and **base_url()** are provided by the url helper.

Answer (score 0):

Use the form helper!

Instead of `<form action="index.php/controller/method">` , which will be interpreted as a relative path, use:

`<?php echo form_open('controller/method'); ?>`

Codeigniter will handle the rest